# Migration of asp to asp.net(c#.net)

Tags: asp-classic, asp.net-2.0

I've a website developed in **classic asp**. 
Now I want to convert it to **asp.net(2.0 or above)**.

How can I do it without coding from scratch?
Can you suggest a free or cheap tool to do the work?

Comment: +1 this question was useful to me...

Answer (score 5):

In my experience when you switch platforms like this you are basically doing a full rewrite.  Any conversion tools that you find will end up producing code that 1) probably doesn't fully work, and 2) is messy code in the destination language that will be hard to maintain.

Then of course there is the bigger problem: **you most likely want an entirely different *architecture* in ASP.NET versus what you had in ASP**.  Better to revisit the requirements of the application, think about the architecture and design, and reimplement.  Use the source code as a guide for how certain pieces work, but don't do a pure conversion.

Comment: Actually i am not looking for a permanent solution. I just need to avoid the performance issue of the current website by using such a converted version until the actual conversion(line by line) is done.For such a temporary purpose can you suggest suitable tool that is free of cost?..

Comment: I'm afraid I've never worked with an ASP > ASP.NET tool.  I've done conversions from/to other platforms.  Do you have evidence that the performance issue will be solved by moving to ASP.NET?  I wouldn't take that as a given.

Comment: As per my knowledge asp interprets the code line by line, where as asp.net is precompiled. That is why i am thinking to improve performance by converting asp to asp.net....

Thanks for your reply.....

Comment: I'm guessing that whatever performance issues you are experienced are not due to the overhead of interpreting ASP.  It is probably related to data retrieval, HTML rendering, JavaScript, and other things.  Those types of things take far more time than interpreting ASP code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any good news here. Automatically translating ASP code to ASP.NET will require a lot of busywork. Perhaps you can farm out to an offshore developer who can do this gruntwork for you?

Comment: When i searched about this i've read about ms migration assistant. Do you know about this?

Comment: I haven't seen that tool, but from very painful past experiences, I can tell you that you're still going to have to pick through your code, line by line, to make sure everything works as it should.  Regardless of what tool you used to port your code.

That's the problem with a rewrite/migration, it's very costly, and it can't be automated fully. You typically want to do it incrementally if at all possible. Try porting a first page
to ASP.NET, and see how much pain that incurs.

I really hope you have unit tests with your website to make sure you're not breaking anything when you port it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename all the pages to .aspx (or of cource configure iis to use .net to process .asp pages). Classic asp runs fine in .net. Now start one page at a time and change only the stuff that actually benifits from being asp.net. Just an option. I'm just saying.

Answer (score 0):

Using **asp to asp.net migration assistant** we can do it. I could convert my asp project to asp.net 1.x using **asp to asp.net migration assistant**.

But there were a few run time errors as well as DB connecting problems after the conversion.........

System Requirements
Supported Operating System
Windows 2000, Windows 98, Windows ME, Windows NT, Windows XP
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 1.1 Redistributable Package

as per http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18312

Comment: which .Net version is supported for that (im using VS2008 and VS2010)..?